# Get current language in non-page component on server side using nextjs and next-i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side, next-i18next

I have a nextjs app which uses [next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) library for internationalization. I don't manage to find a way to get the current language on **server-side** in a component **which is not a page**.

The current language can be retrieved on server side from the request object passed to *getInitialProps*, but getInitialProps is available only for pages. A solution would be to get the language in the page component and to send it down to my component via props, but I don't find it very beautiful.

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding a prop to the component you are using.